# Unicycle-like robot simulation

Tags: control

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to simulate the behavior of a unicycle under the action of different control laws. Are there any valid and available already made modules for unicycle-like robot simulations? Which one can fit better for this aim?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3879/unicycle-like-robot-simulation/) by [martz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/447/martz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'd have to make your own model. Look at some existing model, like the pioneer2dx, to get an idea of how SDF works.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0